# Capybara::InfiniteRedirectError: redirected more than 5 times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Hola al intentar correr mis pruebas con capybara me lanza ese error no entiendo porque, que estoy haciendo mal?

este es el error:

```
Failures:

  1) Users editar usuario edicion exitosa
     Failure/Error: click_button 'Grabar'

     Capybara::InfiniteRedirectError:
       redirected more than 100 times, check for infinite redirects.
```

Este es mi tes de pruebas

```
  require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Users", type: :feature do
  context "crear nuevo usuario" do
    scenario "creacion exitosa" do
      user= FactoryBot.create(:user, :super_usuario)
      login_as(user, :scope => :user)
      visit new_user_path
      within('#frm_user') do 
       fill_in('user_user', with: 'elusuario')
       fill_in('user_name', with: 'Jhon Smith')
       fill_in('user_email', with: 'jsmith@hotmail.com')
       select('Cliente', from: 'user[roles]')
       fill_in('user_password', with: '123456')
      end
       click_button 'Grabar'
       expect(page).to have_content('Jhon Smith')  
    end  
  end

  context "editar usuario" do

    scenario "edicion exitosa" do
      user= FactoryBot.create(:user, :super_usuario)
      login_as(user, :scope => :user)
      visit edit_user_path(user)
      within('#frm_user') do 
       fill_in('user_user', with: 'marco')
       fill_in('user_name', with: 'Marco Smith')
       fill_in('user_email', with: 'ppp@hotmail.com')
       select('Cliente', from: 'user[roles]')
      end
       click_button 'Grabar'
       expect(page).to have_content('Marco Smith')  
    end  

    scenario "fallo al actualizar" do
    end 
  end

  context "eliminar usuario" do 
  end  
end
```

Este es mi controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy], :except => :change_password

  add_breadcrumb "users", :users_path


  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    add_breadcrumb "", users_path
    @users = User.all
    authorize @users
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    add_breadcrumb @user.id, user_path(@user)
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    add_breadcrumb "New", new_user_path
    @flag_nuevo_usuario=true
    @user = User.new
    authorize @user
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
     add_breadcrumb @user.id, edit_user_path(@user)
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @flag_nuevo_usuario=true
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    authorize @user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Usuario creado satisfactoriamente.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|

      if @user.update(user_params_update)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Usuario fue actualizado.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'Usuario ha sido eliminado.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def show_modal_change_password
    set_user
  end

  def change_password
    set_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(change_password_params)
        format.js
      else
        mensaje="Error: Ocurrio un error al actualizar el password"
        format.js{render :js => "alert('#{mensaje}');"}  
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      authorize @user
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:user,:name,:roles, :email, :password)
    end

    def user_params_update
      params.require(:user).permit(:user,:name,:roles, :email)
    end

    def change_password_params
      params.permit(:password)
    end

end
```

Esta es mi clase use_policy

```
class UserPolicy < AdminPolicy

  def show_modal_change_password?
    es_super_usuario?
  end

  def change_password?
    es_super_usuario?
  end


end
```

La cual hereda de AdminPolicy

```
class AdminPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index?
    es_super_usuario? || es_gerente_general?
  end

  def show?
    #scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
    es_super_usuario?
  end

  def create?
    es_super_usuario? 
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    es_super_usuario?
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    es_super_usuario?
  end
end
```

Esta es mi traza de error:

```
Failures:

  1) Users editar usuario edicion exitosa
     Failure/Error: click_button 'Grabar'

     Capybara::InfiniteRedirectError:
       redirected more than 5 times, check for infinite redirects.
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:46:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:32:in `submit'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/form.rb:80:in `submit'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/node.rb:64:in `click'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:143:in `block in click'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:143:in `click'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:61:in `click_button'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:808:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/users_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:97:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.1/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:16:in `cleaning'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.1/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:98:in `cleaning'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.1/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # /home/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails_5_gemset/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.1/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:96:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Comparte el code de tu controlador, el error es por un redirect que se ejecuta muchas veces en el action create.

Comment: hola William ya coloque el codigo de mi controller, pero no se en que pueda estar redireccionandose

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código donde tienes el método `authorize`?

Comment: Instala la gema byebug y haz seguimiento en el controlador, es posible que, como indica @Gerry sea un problema con el login del usuario, al tratar de entrar al edit no tiene los permisos necesarios y eso origina los redirects.

Comment: El methodo authorize es propio de la gema pundit, que me sirve para autorizar el acceso. He añadido mi clase Policy

Comment: ¿Qué te muestra el log si hace la prueba en el navegador?

Comment: Hola Gerry , acabo de añadir mi traza de error.

Comment: Ese log es específicamente de la prueba, pero no deja ver mucho detalle; para entender mejor el error, prueba tu aplicación desde el navegador (i.e. no corriendo la prueba de RSpec) y agrega el error que muestra el log del servidor.

Comment: @Gerry cuando dices probar desde navegador te refieres a que lo ejecute con selenium? o abro mi navegador y sea yo quien interactue ? porque si es abrir el navegador funciona bien el problema es en la prueba, lo raro es que la prueba que falla es la de editar usuario, pero en la prueba crear nuevo usuario si funciona eso es lo raro

Comment: Me refería a abrir el navegador, pero ya me confirmas que así sí funciona. Con esta información no puedo decirte dónde pueda estar el error, es necesario tomar más tiempo para depurar el código. Podrías seguir la recomendación de @WilliamWongGaray y utilizar byebug para localizar el error.