# Postgres guarda datos json con caracteres \"

Tags: json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, jsonp

Al guardar el json en una columna jsonb en Postgres, lo guarda con este formato

"{amigo:  [{\"nombre\":\"paolo\",\"valor\":\"guerrero\"},{\"nombre\":\"(label)\",\"valor\":\"\"}]}"

yo le estoy enviando esto desde ruby on rails

```
 @proyecto.update(campos: '{"amigo": ' + ' [{"nombre":"paolo","valor":"guerrero"},{"nombre":"(label)","valor":""}]' + "}")
```

Porque pasa esto? porque postgres cambia las comillas dobles " con  \", y como puedo hacer para que en mi base de datos se grabe con este formato

```
{"amigo": [{"nombre":"paolo","valor":"guerrero"},{"nombre":"(label)","valor":""}]}
```

Ayuda porfavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se debe a que estás generando un *string*, pero para guardar en la columna `jsonb` debes utilizar un *hash*.

Consola de rails (`$ rails s`):

```
campos = {
  "amigo": [
    {nombre:"paolo",valor:"guerrero"},
    {nombre:"(label)",valor:""}
  ]
}
#=> {:amigo=>[{:nombre=>"paolo", :valor=>"guerrero"}, {:nombre=>"(label)", :valor=>""}]}

@proyecto.update(campos: campos)
#=> true

@proyecto.campos
#=> {"amigo"=>[{"nombre"=>"paolo", "valor"=>"guerrero"}, {"nombre"=>"(label)", "valor"=>""}]}
```

Consola de bd (`$ rails db`):

```
=# select * from tabla;
1 | {"amigo": [{"valor": "guerrero", "nombre": "paolo"}, {"valor": "", "nombre": "(label)"}]}
```

Como podrás ver, aunque en la consola de rails el valor se muestra como *hash*, en la base de datos se guarda como *json*.

Comment: Hola pero , lo que yo quiero es guardarlo en la base de datos postgres de esta forma {"amigo": [{"nombre":"paolo","valor":"guerrero"},{"nombre":"(label)","valor":""}]}  Por ejemplo si yo hago un insert y le mando el valor desde SQl si graba en el formato que quiero pero desde Rails no

Comment: El problema que se guarde en la base de datos con \" , es que no me funcionan mis consultas en jsonb desde ruby on rails.

Comment: @HalleyRios Ya entiendo, el problema es como estás generando el valor para el campo; mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Uhm pero el simbolo => no es leido en formato json al guardarlo como hash. He intentado probar con .to_json pero apesar que cuando hago un put mivariable lo imprime en formato json pero cuando lo guardo no

Comment: @HalleyRios ¿Exactamente que operación estás tratando de hacer? Acabo de probar el código y puedo manipular el _hash_  sin problema.

Comment: @HalleyRios Es importante mencionar que lo que ves como resultado en rails ya está convertido a un _hash_, pero en la base de datos está como _json_; por eso ves el símbolo `=>` (he actualizado la respuesta).

Comment: efectivamente funciono se guarda en la base de datos. Gracias por la respuesta. Necesitaba convertirlo a Hash. Lo que si no se es si mi procedimiento es muy largo ya que primero mi array de json lo parse y luego lo inclui en el hash a lo mejor hay una forma mas rapida pero me funcion. Mil Gracias

Comment: Acabo de aceptar tu respuesta. Gracias @Gerry

Comment: Hola @Gerry acabo de actualizar el procedimiento , he agregado el codigo en vue y la data que se envia.

Comment: me lanza un error al momento de aplicar el slice.   TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)

Comment: @HalleyRios La respuesta que buscas ya es distinta a la pregunta original (la cual ya se respondió), sugiero que abras una nueva pregunta, de lo contrario esta respuesta se volverá un hilo interminable y perdería el sentido que busca SO.

Comment: esta bien, solo hice una correcion al hash para que otros les funcione. Pero en sintesis lo que tenia que enviar era un hash como dijiste.

Comment: @HalleyRios Excelente! Que bueno que funcionó y espero si hayas logrado reducir el código necesario para realizar la función.

Comment: Si muchas Gracias por la ayuda, aunque te comento que lo del slice no me funciono ya que me dio error lo hice de la manera larga con el JSONParse, pero igual lo de el hash fue trascendental para poder lograr lo que buscaba. Muchas Gracias. Por cierto hay alguna forma en que te pueda contactar para alguna duda adicional?

Comment: @HalleyRios ¿Qué tipo de dudas? ¿Son demasiado amplias para realizarlas en SO? Generalmente prefiero utilizar SO ya que puedes obtener ayuda de más de 1 persona y, además, podría también ayudar a otras personas que puedan tener dudas similares en el futuro.

Comment: bueno son dudas mas que todo respecto jsonb con Rails , solo que a veces no siempre responden algunas preguntas. En esta ocasion tu respuesta fue rapida y me has ahorrado un buen tiempo. Saludos

Comment: podrias ayudarme con esta otra pregunta? . No he podido dar con la solucion  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163348/capybarainfiniteredirecterror-redirected-more-than-5-times